# How to draw a line on UIWebView (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, draw, vector-graphics

I have a UIWebView with a custom map (vector image/svg) loaded. I would like to draw lines on that image. The image can be zoomed in/out so the line has to respond to that as well (which is why having another uiview as a subview won't work for me). What is the easiest way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I can have the line as a vector image/svg and use html to embed that line over the custom map but not sure if that is possible in html (layering vector images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really an "easy" way to do this. `UIWebView` is just a viewer, it gives you no control over editing or anything else.

If you want full control (over a map, or anything else you can load in a UIWebview), you have to implement it another way (using MKMapView or whatever the API is (no experience with it)). For instance, if you want to do a real PDF viewer (page flipping, showing annotations, etc) you use `CGPDFDocument` and associated APIs, not `UIWebView`.

MKMapView's class reference can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)

Comment: I have struggled a lot with MKMapView it seems to be much tougher to manage what I am trying to do than on UIWebView.. Would creating an html page and then loading it work? I am skeptical as I am not sure if html/css can do vector image layering

Comment: yes, as long as you aren't trying to edit the UIWebViews content directly you should be ok, but i'm no where near an expert with html/javascript and the such for iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no "real" way todo this, a work around would be (if you don't need zooming) to put a `UIView` on top of the `UIWebView`, on this view you could draw.
There are some work around to zoom the `UIView` same way as the `UIWebView`, but these are all workarounds that do not work well.

Also `CGPDFDocument` are no real workarounds, as you there also have really limited methods to draw etc.

Best option would be to use a `MKMapView` with overlay.